# R-package text encoding - special characters encoded incorrectly

Tags: r

I've got an R-function along these lines:

```
swedish.weekday <- function(date = Sys.Date()) {
  require(lubridate)
  c("Sön", "Mån", "Tis", "Ons", "Tor", "Fre", "Lör")[wday(date)]
}
```

This returns the three letter equivalent of Sun, Mon, Tue etc.

Works absolutely fine until I include this function in a package where during the build the function transforms into:

```
swedish.weekday <- function(date = Sys.Date()) {
  require(lubridate)
  c("SÃ¶n", "MÃ¥n", "Tis", "Ons", "Tor", "Fre", "LÃ¶r")[wday(date)]
}
```

I've tried setting the encoding options in the project settings to either ISO8859-1 or WINDOWS-1252 but neither works. Using 64 bit R 3.1.2 under Windows 7.

Suspect I'd need to change something in the build config but I'm lost as to what - any help/direction much appreciated!

Comment: Be sure to read the [encoding issues](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Encoding-issues) section of the Writing R Extensions Guide. You need to know what encoding you used when you wrote your file rather than guessing. You can look at `sessionInfo()$locale` to see what encoding R is defaulting to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the link posted in the comments above I solved the issue by merely using Unicode escapes as such:

```
day <- c("S\u00F6n", "M\u00E5n", "Tis", "Ons", "Tor", "Fre", "L\u00F6r")[wday(date)]
```

Edit: While passing these results to an external system (OLAP) I discovered it is also necessary to force the encoding of these results to ISO ("latin-9") to ensure it does not only look correct on the screen but also as far as the system is concerned as such `day <- inconv(day, "UTF-8", "latin-9")`

For ref...

> There is a portable way to have arbitrary text in character strings (only) in your R code, which is to supply them in Unicode as \uxxxx escapes. If there are any characters not in the current encoding the parser will encode the character string as UTF-8 and mark it as such. This applies also to character strings in datasets: they can be prepared using \uxxxx escapes or encoded in UTF-8 in a UTF-8 locale, or even converted to UTF-8 via ‘iconv()’. If you do this, make sure you have ‘R (>= 2.10)’ (or later) in the ‘Depends’ field of the DESCRIPTION file.